# What is the reason of below error in vespa.ai?

Tags: vespa

We are facing this below error in Vespa, after restarting the cluster we got this below issue.

```
1600455444.680758       10.10.000.00    1030/1  container       Container.com.yahoo.filedistribution.fileacquirer.FileAcquirerImpl      info    Retrying waitFor for file 'e0ce64d459828eb0': 103 -- Request timed out after 60.0 seconds.
1600455446.819853       10.10.000.00    32752/146       configproxy     configproxy.com.yahoo.vespa.filedistribution.FileReferenceDownloader    info    Request failed. Req: request filedistribution.serveFile(e0ce64d459828eb0,0)\nSpec: tcp/10.10.000.00:19070, error code: 103, set error for connection and use another for next request
```

We faced this issue second time, earlier we kept it ideal and it was resolved automatically, but this time it is persistent.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like the `configproxy` is unable to talk to the config server (which is listening to port 19070 on the same host: `Spec: tcp/10.10.000.00:19070`). Is the config server really runnning and listening on port 19070 on this host? Try running the `vespa-config-status` script to see if all is well with the config system

Comment: I tried running "vespa-config-status", I am getting "Failed to fetch json: Connection error: socker write error". but when I am running "sudo service vespa-configserver status" it is "active"

Comment: There is definitely something wrong with your setup, but hard to say what it is without more information. You could look for errors or warnings in the log, try restarting config server and services and deploy the application again.